# JSON parsing swift 3

Tags: json, swift, parsing

```
if statusCode == 200 {
    let json = response.result.value as? NSDictionary
    print("JSON FILE")
    //print(json)
    let companies = json?["companies"] as? [AnyObject]
    print(companies)
    for value in companies! {
        let address = value["address"] as? String
        print(address)
        let schedule = companies?["schedule"] as? [AnyObject]// as? NSDictionary
        print(schedule)
            for sch in schedule! {
        }
    }
}
```

**Here json file**

```
  {
      "code": "200",
      "message": "OK",
      "companies": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "img": "doxsun.jpg",
          "schedule": [
            {
              "id": "1",
              "company_id": "1",
              "day": "0",
              "time_from": "06:00:00",
              "time_to": "23:00:00"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "img": "zalypa.jpg",
          "schedule": []
        }
      ]
 }
```

I have a problem with json file parsing how correctly parse it? I can't parse schedule. How to convert all this types?               words to pass quality. words to pass quality.words to pass quality.words to pass quality.words to pass quality.words to pass quality.words to pass quality.words to pass quality.words to pass quality.words to pass quality.

Comment: What's the error? How do you make the request? Are you using Alamofire or AFNetworking? Can you show us your full code and the error you get?

Comment: alamofire response json

Comment: error in schedule 
cannot subscript a value type anyobject with an index type of string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some conversion issues with correct types using `as` operator. I believe the below code should allow you to iterate through schedules of each company:

```
if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
  if let companies = JSON["companies"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
    for company in companies {
      if let schedules = company["schedule"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
        for schedule in schedules {
          // do something with the schedule
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //return 2 //datamodel.count
        return newarr.count
    }

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: tblCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! tblCell
     self.json = newarr.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary

    cell.lblName.text = json.value(forKey: "artistName") as? String


    return cell
}
```

}

extension ViewController {
    func swiftyJson(){

```
    let url = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson")
    //let url = URL(string: "http://makani.bitstaging.in/api/business/businesses_list")

    Alamofire.request(url!, method: .get, parameters: nil).responseJSON { response in

        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):

                let data = response.result.value as! NSDictionary
                self.newarr = data.value(forKey: "results")as! NSArray

                print(self.newarr)
                self.tblView.reloadData()
            break

        case .failure(_):
            print(response.result.error as Any)
            break

        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

let url = URL(string: "https://api.androidhive.info/contacts")
        Alamofire.request(url!, method: .get, parameters: nil).responseJSON { response in

```
        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):

            if let dicData = response.result.value as? [String : Any]{

                if let arrOfCartDetails = Mapper<BaseDataModel>().map(JSON: dicData) {
                    self.arrData.append(arrOfCartDetails)
                    print(self.arrData)
                    if self.arrData.count > 0{
                        self.arrContect = self.arrData[0].contacts!
                        print(self.arrContect[0].phone?.home)

                    }
                    if self.arrContect.count > 0{
                        self.tblDemo.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            break

        case .failure(_):
            print(response.result.error as Any)
            break

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
        Alamofire.request(url!, method: .get, parameters: nil).responseJSON { response in

```
        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            if let data = response.result.value as? [[String : Any]]{
                if Mapper<DocumentDataModel>().mapArray(JSONArray: data).count > 0{
                    self.arrDataModel = Mapper<DocumentDataModel>().mapArray(JSONArray: data)
                    print(self.arrDataModel)
                    let banner = self.arrDataModel[0]
                    print("userId", banner.userId)

                    if self.arrDataModel.count > 0{
                        self.tblDemo.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
            break

        case .failure(_):
            print(response.result.error as Any)
            break

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

let url = "https://reqres.in/api/products"

```
    AF.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil).responseJSON{ (response) in
            switch(response.result) {

            case .success(let responseString):
                print("Success")
               // print(responseString)
               let User = Mapper<Response>().map(JSONObject:responseString)
               // print(User)
                
                self.arrayFavouriteJobList = (User?.data)!
                print(self.arrayFavouriteJobList)
                self.tblData.reloadData()

                break

            case .failure(_):
                print(response.error as Any)
                break

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

func apiCalling(){

```
    let url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
    
    AF.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in
        
        if let responseData = response.data{
            print(response)
            do{
                let decodeJson = JSONDecoder()
                decodeJson.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                self.responseData = try decodeJson.decode([DataModel].self, from: responseData)
                self.tblData.reloadData()
            }catch{
                
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, headers: nil).responseJSON{response in

        switch response.result{

        case.success:


            print("sucess")

            if let JSON = response.result.value
            {

                self.hk = JSON as! NSDictionary

                print(self.hk)

                print(((self.hk.value(forKey: "contacts")as! NSArray).object(at: 4        )as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "name")as! NSString)

                self.flag = 1
                self.tbl1.reloadData()


            }
        case.failure(let Error):

            print("error\(Error)")




        }



    }





}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if flag == 0
    {
        return 0
    }
    else
    {
        return (self.hk.value(forKey: "contacts")as! NSArray).count

    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tbl1.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)as! TableViewCell1

    cell.lbl1.text = (((self.hk.value(forKey: "contacts")as! NSArray).object(at: indexPath.row)as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "name")as!String)

    return cell

}
```

Answer (score -1):

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{

```
var hk : NSDictionary = NSDictionary()

let url = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson"

@IBOutlet var tblview: UITableView!
var flag = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    getdata()
}

func getdata()
{

    //let url = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson"

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, headers: nil).responseJSON{response in

        switch response.result{

        case.success:


            print("sucess")

            if let JSON = response.result.value
            {

                self.hk = JSON as! NSDictionary

                print(self.hk)


                print(((self.hk.value(forKey: "results")as! NSArray).object(at: 0)as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "artworkUrl60")as! NSString)

                //print(((self.hk.value(forKey: "contacts")as! NSArray).object(at: 4        )as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "name")as! NSString)

                self.flag = 1
                self.tblview.reloadData()


            }
        case.failure(let Error):

            print("error\(Error)")



        }

        }

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if flag == 0
    {
        return 0
    }
    else
    {

    return (self.hk.value(forKey: "results")as! NSArray).count

    }

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)as! TableViewCell1


    let imageURL = NSURL(string: (((self.hk.value(forKey: "results")as! NSArray).object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "artworkUrl60") as! String))

    let imagedData = NSData(contentsOf: imageURL! as URL)!

    cell.img1.image = UIImage(data: imagedData as Data)




    return cell
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let bh = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "imageViewController")as!imageViewController


    bh.str = (((self.hk.value(forKey: "results")as! NSArray).object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "artworkUrl60") as! String)




    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(bh, animated: true)

}
```

Answer (score -1):

// swifty Json
 func jsonParsing(){

```
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.androidhive.info/contacts/")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

        guard let data = data else { return }
        do{
            let json = JSON(data:data)
            let contacts = json["contacts"][5]["phone"].dictionaryValue

            print(contacts)

        }
        catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        }.resume()

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
func jsonParsing(){

    let url = URL(string: "https://api.androidhive.info/contacts/")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

        guard let data = data else { return }
        do{
            let json = JSON(data:data)
            let contacts = json["contacts"]
            let name = contacts["name"]
            for arr in contacts.arrayValue{
                print(arr["name"])
            }

            //prinerrrr)

        }
        catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        }.resume()

    }
}
```